# LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'glfw3.lib'

Tags: file-management, visual-studio

I am **trying** to use OpenGL. Yet, every time i use Visual Studio and press Local Windows debugger I get the error above (LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'glfw3.lib').

My file structure is this

```
DOCUMENTS
 - Visual Studio 2019
   - Projects
     - OpenGlProject
       - sln and everything else
 - External Libs
   - GLFW
     - include
       - glfw3.h
     - lib-vc2019
       - glfw3.lib
   - GLEW
     - include
       - GL
         - all glew.h files
     - lib
       - Release
         - Win32
           -glew32.lib
```

I am including the .h files with

```
$(SolutionDir)/../../../ExternalLibs/GLEW/include
$(SolutionDir)/../../../ExternalLibs/GLFW/include
```

The lib files are included with

```
$(SolutionDir)/../../../ExternalLibs GLFW/lib-vc2019
$(SolutionDir)/../../../ExternalLibs/GLEW/lib/Release/Win32
```

The linker input files look like this

```
opengl32.lib
glew32.lib
glew32s.lib
glfw3.lib
```

I thought I was doing everything right, so what is the problem? I've looked everywhere and nothing useful has come up. Thanks for the help in advance, cheers!

Stack Overflow Link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57990632/link-fatal-error-lnk1104-cannot-open-file-glfw3-lib